# Ubuntu 18.04, Encrypted Drives, NVidia Drivers

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, encryption

I write this after weeks of googling and testing differing options.
I have a Dell XPS, it has a GTX1050 within. I also have encrypted my disks. Upon it is Ubuntu 18.04

Although the laptop works fine, it fails to detect the laptop monitor "Unknown Monitor" and also its unable to detect the massive LG 2nd monitor I have attached to the hdmi port.

So I thought installing the nvidia drivers would help me.

Upon reboot I get a flashing
[error mesage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DX6J.jpg)

Only way to continue is get into the cli, and purge nvidia* and reboot

Ive tried updating grub, so that instead of the splash, its text.

At this point I get a Nvidia Persistance Daemon starting and stopping. But proceeds no further.

Please can someone point me in the direction I should be looking? Its driving me nuts.
Thanks